# Android: manage USB memory and files

Tags: permissions, usb-mass-storage

Good afternoon to all.

I'm working on Android 4.0.3 (API 15).

I'd need to make an application that mounts automatically a USB stick (when connected), copies some files from it to internal file system and unmounts it (when finished the copy).

I'm getting crazy to mount/unmount the mass storage:

I tried to use the methods contained in **IMountService.java** (under android.os.storage) that allows to mount/unmount storage from a given mount point (i.e. unmountVolume or mountVolume) but, when I invoke them, the application crashes.

You can find IMountService.java class at the following link:

http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/storage/IMountService.java

I also tried to obtain the mount/unmount permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permissions android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

but nothing...

I've looked deeply in the forum (and on all the resources I found) but I have no idea...maybe the device must be rooted to do this operation?

Can someone help me to find an easy way to mount and unmount external storages?

thank you in advance

Alessandro

Comment: Look in the app store for "mount USB host". There are a lot of apps like this but they require root.